# Help! Requesting a change of URL on Yahoo Directory!

Tags: yahoo, directory

I submitted a couple websites on yahoo directory a month ago. For some reason, the url they listed was not the url I asked for, they listed the Japanese version instead of the submitted English version (this is a English directory so obviously it is a mistake).

I requested changes and was accepted. But the reality is they promised a change but it was never really done. I contacted them again and again through the 'request a change in URL' form, but there is no answer.

Is there any effective way that I can get to them? preferably a phone number or email?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Yahoo is now powered by bing - have you tried using [bing webmaster tools](http://www.bing.com/toolbox/webmaster/) to request the change?